# angularjsでイメージファイルをservletに送信したい。

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs

いつもお世話になっております。
angularjsでイメージファイル(MultipartFile)をサーブレットに送信したいのですが、
springの@RequestParamアノテーションで上手く取得できません。

jsp

```
<form method="POST" id="image-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="imageFile" name="imageFile" accept="image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/png" />
    <div id="search-button">
        <input type="button" ng-click="searchCtrl.imageSearch();">
    </div>
</form>
```

javascript

```
var $form;
var formData = new FormData();

$form = $("#image-form");
formData.append("imageFile", $form[0]);

request = $http({
    method : 'post',
    url : "/addImage",
    data : data,
    headers : {
        'Content-Type' : undefined
    },
    transformRequest : null
});

return (request.then(handleSuccess, handleError));
```

java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addImage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public List<SearchImageRequestModel> logo_upload(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
    Model model, @PathVariable("service_id") String serviceId, @RequestParam(value = "imageFile") MultipartFile file)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
...
```

@RequestParamではMultipartFileは取得できないのでしょうか。
恐れ入りますが、ご教示のほどお願い致します。

追記
jsでファイルがちゃんと取得できていませんでした。
以下の書き方で正常に取得できました。

```
$('#imageFile').prop('files')[0].name;
```

Comment: transformRequestをnullにしているせいでデータが渡っていないのではないですか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。

以下のHPを参考にさせて頂いたので、データが渡っていないという事は無いかと考えておりました。
http://qiita.com/sashimizakana/items/23ddd656703c38626cc2

実際、このロジックを実行すると$httpサービスで送信するタイミングで415 （Unsupported media type）エラーが発生するので、アノテーションの設定に問題があるかと睨んでおります。